# Italic shape needed in small caps fonts

Tags: fonts, small-caps, italic

I am using MiKTeX 2.5 version. Is there any possibility to change the small caps fonts in italic shape?

I had tried as like below

```
\textit{\textsf{Small Caps}}% This will gives the Regular Small caps output.
\textsf{\textit{Small Caps}}% This will gives the italic output.
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Your MiKTeX version (2.5) is *heavily* outdated and not supported anymore. I suggest you update to the most recent version: [MiKTeX 2.9](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup).

Comment: presumably you mean `\textsc` not `textsf`

Comment: You may try this: `\usepackage{smallcap}`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a combination of [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) and [`slantsc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/slantsc) to obtain slanted small caps:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern
\usepackage{slantsc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/slantsc
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb!\textsc{Hello world}! & \textsc{Hello world} \\ % Regular Small Caps
  \verb!\textsl{Hello world}! & \textsl{Hello world} \\ % Regular slanted
  \verb!\textit{Hello world}! & \textit{Hello world} \\ % Regular italics
  \verb!\textit{\textsc{Hello world}}! & \textit{\textsc{Hello world}} \\ % No italic small caps exist, this is substituted for default font
  \verb!\textsl{\textsc{Hello world}}! & \textsl{\textsc{Hello world}} % Slanted small caps
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you're specifically after italic small caps in Times font, consider reading

<del>http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/sterratt/progs/italic-small-caps-times-latex</del>

http://www.sterratt.me.uk/progs/italic-small-caps-times-latex

The above source provides [`times-itsc`](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/sterratt/files/times-itsc.tgz) that you could use *instead of* your preferred Times package to produce italicized small caps.

Comment: If this answer solved your original problem, you should consider upvoting (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and/or accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark). This shows the answer helped you, and it assigns reputation points, even to you! And, with higher [reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) comes more [privileges](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Comment: Thank you somuch for your help.. i had tried with the above example, i am getting the required outout. Wnen i used both this packages the output is comes like below                 "Lower case letters come in lowercase" "Upper case letter as come as uppercase"... could you please help me on this on times font... i can't able to attached the screen sort here..

Comment: @Saravanan.O: If you're interested in Times italicized small caps, follow the link in my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Werner, thank you very much for your help.. currently i'm not having the time-itsc package. i had searched also in the internet. if possible could you please provide the link for downloading the style files

Comment: @Werner thx for that solution, I just came across it when having the same problem. But: your example - run on a standard TeXLive2014 - produces no italics small caps on the `\textit{\textsc{...}}` line and warns `Font shape `OT1/lmr/m/scit' undefined`. It is necessary to replace italics small caps by slanted small caps as described in the `slantsc` doc (p.4) as so: `\rmfamily
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmr}{m}{scit}{<->ssub * lmr/m/scsl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{scit}{<->ssub * lmr/bx/scsl}{}
` - and analogous if using `T1` of course.

Comment: on the need for the `\rmfamily` see [here](http://fr.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/5obuKnfv/substitution-de-petites-capitales-avec-lmodern) (in french though..)

Comment: `\usepackage{cfr-lm}` ... `\textsi{italic small-caps}` Or `\textit{\textsc{italic small-caps}}` or `\textsc{\textit{small-caps italic}}`. At least, that's the theory.

Comment: [And practice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284390/), it seems. Today, anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wake to fake it with any font (based on my answer at [Small Caps in Description Label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230334/small-caps-in-description-label/230336#230336)).  Compare the first FAUX line to the REAL line to see a comparison of quality.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\fauxsc[1]{\fauxschelper#1 \relax\relax}
\def\fauxschelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \fauxschelphelp#1\relax\relax%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else\ \fauxschelper#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\Hscale{.85}\def\Vscale{.74}\def\Cscale{1.12}
\def\fauxschelphelp#1#2\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1>``\ifnum`#1<`\{\scalebox{\Hscale}[\Vscale]{\uppercase{#1}}\else%
    \scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi\else\scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxschelphelp#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}

\fauxsc{Why not small caps?} FAUX\par
\textsc{Why not small caps?} REAL

\textit{\fauxsc{Why not Italic small caps?}} FAUX
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fake italic small-caps are not recommended, any more than fake small-caps or fake italic. In general, faked glyphs always involve a compromise in quality.

This answer highlights a few options for real italic and oblique small-caps, including an option for a Times-like font.

[I am not sure that 'oblique' and 'italic' are distinct in the case of small-caps, so am just covering all possible eventualities.]

Latin Modern provides italic small-caps fonts but these are not supported by the default **lmodern** support package. **cfr-lm** does support them, however:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
The following three are equivalent:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textsi{Small-caps Italic}
  \item \textit{\textsc{Italic Small-caps}}
  \item \textsc{\textit{Small-caps Italic}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: italic small-caps Latin Modern]

The same code works for

```
\usepackage{venturis}
```

[image: italic small-caps Venturis ADF]

```
\usepackage{electrum}
```

[image: italic small-caps Electrum ADF]

```
\usepackage{berenis}
```

[image: italic small-caps Berenis ADF]

TeX-Gyre Termes is an enhanced clone of Times which includes italic small-caps:

[image: italic small-caps TeX-Gyre Termes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\begin{document}
\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italic Small-caps
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use `\usepackage{cfr-lm}` I no longer have bold small caps.. :(  Is there a way to have both?

Comment: @MaxN Latin Modern doesn't include bold small-caps. So the only way `cfr-lm` can provide these is if you persuade the GUST developers to add bold small-caps. You have to use a font with both bold and italic small-caps *and* a font package which supports these. `cfr-lm` provides access to what exists; it cannot fix existentially-challenged fonts.

Comment: I understand, but I need italic small caps at another point in my document. Can I say to use another font for all bold occurances?

Comment: @MaxN You could, but it would not be recommended. You would be much better choosing fonts which provide everything you need. Mixing regular small-caps with bold small-caps from another font is going to look weird. Consistency isn't everything, but it is a great deal.

Comment: do you know of a font that has slanted small-caps as well as bold small-caps and mabe even bold italic small-caps?

Comment: @MaxN Not off the top of my head. But take a look through the LaTeX Font Catalogue to see what's available for traditional TeX engines.

Comment: @MaxN I think kpfonts does, for example.