# Small Caps in Description Label?

Tags: fonts, lists, description

The description environment allows an optional heading, like `\item [<heading>] text`, to be used. By default this makes the text `<heading>` bold.

I'm having the issue that this style of heading text is overriding my `\textsc{}`.

Why won't the description environment honor my `\textsc{}`?

Here's a picture:

> [image]

And a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

This is normal text. \textsc{This is in small caps.}

\begin{description}
\item [\textsc{Why not small caps?}] Why isn't the text at left in small caps?
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no small caps bold in the standard fonts.

Comment: `\item [\mdseries\textsc{Why not small caps?}]` will turn off bold, thereby making small caps accessible

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I think the design feature of description/itemize etc. lists is that the item - leadin is **bold**, to be an eye-catcher.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  True.  That's why I provide `\fauxsc` in my answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Seen it already... A `\fakesc` solution ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can fake bold small caps with my `\fauxsc{}`, first described at [Fake small caps with XeTeX/fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec/225078#225078).  There are three parameters for tuning the fauxsc font

```
\def\Hscale{.85}\def\Vscale{.72}\def\Cscale{1.10}
```

which define the horizontal scale on lc letters, the vertical scale on lc letters, and the horizontal scale on uc letters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\fauxsc[1]{\fauxschelper#1 \relax\relax}
\def\fauxschelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \fauxschelphelp#1\relax\relax%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else\ \fauxschelper#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\Hscale{.85}\def\Vscale{.72}\def\Cscale{1.10}
\def\fauxschelphelp#1#2\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1>``\ifnum`#1<`\{\scalebox{\Hscale}[\Vscale]{\uppercase{#1}}\else%
    \scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi\else\scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxschelphelp#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}

This is normal text. \textsc{This is in small caps.}

\begin{description}
\item [\fauxsc{Why not small caps?}] Why isn't the text at left in small caps?
\end{description}

\fauxsc{Why not small caps?} FAUX

\textsc{Why not small caps?} REAL
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just fake the bold? Just shift and overstrike.

Comment: @alexis While either approach can be attempted, it is my experience that double-striked characters are much more prone to noticeable flaws than faking small caps via asymmetric stretching.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the labels in a `description` to use small caps, the easiest way is to use `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont\scshape}

\begin{document}

This is normal text. \textsc{This is in small caps.}

\begin{description}
\item [It's small caps] as you clearly see
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason why you don't get small caps is that the standard fonts have no bold small caps, so a substitute is used. Using `\item[\textsc{x}]` just *adds* `\scshape` to the default font, which is boldface. You might do

```
\item[\normalfont\textsc{x}]
```

but the best is to change the default font.