# Lowercase caps for part of caption text

Tags: captions

I would like to change a portion of text in a caption to lowercase caps, not the entire caption text. textsc-ing the portion I want in small capitals does not work. How do I accomplish this ?

One of the commenters requested that I post a minimum working example which I have done below. The sig-alternate style used in the example can be downloaded [here](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls).

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{Figures/myfig.eps}
\caption{Sample caption with \textsc{small caps} for some portion.}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If it doesn't work, this means most probably, that your font doesn't have small caps

Comment: That class file looks a little bit weird

Comment: As far as I could see, the class file uses `ae` fonts, which don't provide small caps

Comment: In such cases where `\scshape` is not available, one can fake it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230334/description-environment-overrides-font-style/230336#230336 with `\fauxsc{}`.  The key to making it look reasonable is a different scale in the vertical and horizontal directions.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I think, you should provide an answer ;-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I tried fauxsc in a caption as : \caption{ This is normal. \fauxsc{This is all in caps.}} . I got an error saying "Argument of \@caption has an extra }".

Comment: Please see my answer.  The `\fauxsc` must be `\protect`ed in a caption.  That can be done explicitly, or the definition of `\fauxsc` can be altered slightly to accommodate that.

Comment: The `sig-alternate` class uses the legacy version of Times provided by TeX distributions, which has *no* small caps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, in such cases where `\scshape` is not available, one can fake it (see [Small Caps in Description Label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230334/description-environment-overrides-font-style/230336#230336)).  Likewise,  the key to making the fake look reasonable is to use a different scale in the vertical and horizontal directions.

When used in the `\caption` environment, however, it must be `\protect`ed.

The values of the horizontal-lc, vertical-lc, and horizontal-uc stretch parameters,

```
\def\Hscale{.80}\def\Vscale{.72}\def\Cscale{1.0}
```

should be tailored to the particular font you are using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand\fauxsc[1]{\fauxschelper#1 \relax\relax}
\def\fauxschelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \fauxschelphelp#1\relax\relax%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else\ \fauxschelper#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\Hscale{.80}\def\Vscale{.72}\def\Cscale{1.0}
\def\fauxschelphelp#1#2\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1>``\ifnum`#1<`\{\scalebox{\Hscale}[\Vscale]{\uppercase{#1}}\else%
    \scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi\else\scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxschelphelp#2\relax\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{Figures/myfig.eps}
\caption{Sample caption with \protect\fauxsc{fake Small Caps} 
  and \textsc{real Small Caps} for some portion.}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, one may `\protect` the argument in the definition itself:

```
\newcommand\fauxsc[1]{\protect\fauxschelper#1 \relax\relax}
```

In this case, the `\protect` is no longer needed in the `\caption` argument.