# Automatically fall back to all-caps if small-caps shapes are missing

Tags: fonts, small-caps

If I use `\textsc{xyz}` with a font that has no small caps (e.g. Latin Modern Sans), the result is typeset in lower case. Is it possible to automatically fallback to all-caps instead? I cannot do this manually since I want to use small caps in a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\acronym}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\acronym{abc} is an acronym.

\begin{description}
\item [\textsc{\acronym{abc}}] Trying to use \textbackslash{}acronym with LM Sans
\item[ABC] This is what it should look like
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or you could just revert to `\fauxsc` in that case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230334/description-environment-overrides-font-style/230336#230336.  A local reassignment of `\let\textsc\fauxsc` in such cases would allow the old syntax to be used.

Comment: I hope your question gets re-opened, as the cited duplicate is not what you intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My original answer referred the OP to my `\fauxsc` macro, but that is not what the OP wanted.  Importantly, the OP wants the discernment of the availability of small caps in the font to be automatic.

So I revised the answer to provide `\detectsc` to detect the presence of small caps or not.  It works by *assuming* that an invocation of `\textsc` in the absence of small caps gets converted to an `\textup` equivalent.  To detect this situation, it places, in two respective boxes, `\textsc{i}` and `\textup{i}`.  It then compares the width and height of these two boxes.  If they are the same, the small caps must be missing, and so it `\let\textsc\uppercase`, which is the behavior desired by the OP in the absence of a small caps font.

REEDITED so that if a valid sc font is detected by `\detectsc`, the original definition of `\textsc` is restored or left intact, as the case may be.  This is important if sc is valid in one font family but not another.

Here is my MWE, which can be compiled under pdflatex (uses lmodern) and the xelatex (uses Myriad Pro), with two different results:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \def\compiler{XeLaTeX}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
  \setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\else
  \def\compiler{pdfLaTeX}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\let\svtextsc\textsc

\newcommand\detectsc{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\textsc{i}}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\textup{i}}%
  \let\textsc\svtextsc%
  \ifdim\wd0=\wd2\ifdim\ht0=\ht2\let\textsc\uppercase\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}
Compiler: \compiler
\sffamily
%\itshape% ALSO WORKS IF ITSHAPE ACTIVATED

\detokenize{\sffamily:}\par
\textsc{Abc} before \detokenize{\detectsc}\par
\detectsc \textsc{Abc} after \detokenize{\detectsc}\par
Resetting \detokenize{\textsc}\rmfamily\let\textsc\svtextsc\par
\detokenize{\rmfamily:}\par
\textsc{Abc} before \detokenize{\detectsc}\par
\detectsc \textsc{Abc} after \detokenize{\detectsc}
\end{document}
```

Here (with lmodern), detecting the distinction between `\textsc` and `\textup`, it leaves `\textsc` intact.

[image]

But under xelatex (with Myriad Pro sans), it detects no distinction in `\sffamily` between `\textup` and `\textsc`, and so it redefines `\textsc` to be `\uppercase`.  However, in `\rmfamily`, it will reinstate or leave intact `\textsc{}` definition.

[image]

Comment: nice! But what about the OP's requirement that `\textsc` is used when shapes are available, and `\fauxsc` is used otherwise, *automatically*?

Comment: @Bordaigorl I do not know enough to do it automatically.  But if I learn how to do so, I will update my answer.

Comment: In fact, this does not answer my question at all. I don't want to have lower quality small caps but *all caps*.

Comment: @Erik, Seeing as this answer does not appeal to you at all, I will delete my answer, after giving you a chance to read this comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm trying to reword my question so it's clearer what I'm looking for. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Erik One last question before I delete the answer.  if you set, in my answer, `\def\Hscale{1}\def\Vscale{1}\def\Cscale{1}`, that will give all regular caps when `\textsc{}` is invoked.  Is that of any use to you, or does this process have to be fully automatic?

Comment: Yes, making it automatic is the point. Otherwise I could just use `\uppercase` (or write capital letters to begin with).