# How to make the \textsc words bold?

Tags: fonts, bold, small-caps

I want the title to be in the font small capital but want them to be bold at the same time

Comment: Then you need to use a font that provides bold small caps, not every font supports that.

Comment: My answer here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230334/small-caps-in-description-label/230336#230336, can allow it to be faked, after a fashion.