# scshape and package tempora

Tags: small-caps

I use tempora fonts and i need to use small caps. If i remove line `\usepackage{tempora}` all works fine. How can i switch fonts while using `\scshape` to get small caps rendered?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora}

\begin{document}

\scshape{Initialize} 

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I need small caps only for latin symbols. Can i somehow change setting for small part of the document to use small caps there?

EDIT:
There are plenty books which contain small caps and cyrillic text. E.g.
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid Tempora has no small caps. :( But does it make sense in Cyrillic text?

Comment: Just a side note (does not address your problem): `\scshape{Initialize}` should be `{\scshape Initialize}` or `\textsc{Initialize}`.

Comment: Checked with NexusFont: Tempora has no small caps.

Comment: You can switch fonts and use small-caps if you switch to a font which has them. But I'm not sure if there are such fonts for Cyrillic ....

Comment: If your application allows the employment of a macro form `\textsc{}` rather than a declaration, `\scshape`, then fake small caps are a possibility, see my `\fauxsc{}` at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec/225078#225078 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230334/small-caps-in-description-label/230336#230336