# How to make a LARGE, bold, and Small Cap font?

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to have a LARGE (`\large`), bold (`\bf`), and small cap (`\sc`) font? I have tried several ways but none of them works as I want.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\textsc{\large Hello World}\\

\textsc{\LARGE Hello World}\\

\textsc{\bf Hello World}\\

\textsc{\LARGE \bf Hello World}\\

\textbf{\textsc{\LARGE Hello World}}\\

\textsc{\textbf{\LARGE Hello World}}\\

\textbf{\LARGE \scshape Hello World}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is primarily due to `\scshape` not having a `\bfseries` version. See [Small Caps and Bold Face](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411/5764)

Comment: Use a font which has bold small caps.

Comment: If you have to fake it, see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230334/small-caps-in-description-label

Comment: Don't under any circumstances fake it.

Comment: @cfr Wʜʏ Nᴏᴛ fake **Sᴍᴀʟʟ Cᴀᴘꜱ** ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I rest my case.