# Italic small caps not working

Tags: fonts, italic, small-caps, latin-modern, slanted

I use small caps with `\textsc{}` a lot, but cannot find a way to get it set in italics. This is primarily a problem inside environments such as theorems, where the theorem text is set in italics, so that `\textsc{}` gives upright small caps. I always load the `fixltx2e` (no longer necessary?) package after reading it enables italic small caps, but that does not seem to be the case. I get slanted small caps with `slantsc`, but since slanted looks rather unappealing for normal text, that does not solve much. Loading different combinations of the packages `fixlte2e`, `fontenc` with T1, and `lmodern` produces different results, none of which are what I want. I have the same problem with Palatino (using `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo})`, except Palatino prints upright lowercase for slanted small caps. I get the warning "Font shape 'T1/lmr/m/scit' undefined(Font) using 'T1/lmr/m/n' instead", which I guess means small-caps-italic font is not available. Is there an easy fix, or is this where one needs other Latex flavors? (I use pdflatex in TeXLive on a Mac.)

Sorry if this is a duplicate -- I could not find the answer anywhere.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|)   \par 
{\slshape gnu}'s not Unix        (\verb|{\slshape }|) \par 
\textit{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|)   \par
\emph{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix}   (\verb|\emph{}|)

\verb|\textsc{}| inside \verb|amsthm| theorem:
\begin{theorem}
  \textsc{gnu}'s not Unix.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE ouput]

Comment: this may be what you're looking for: [Italic shape needed in small caps fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32942/579).

Comment: I you want to consider using `fourier`, for maths, `erewhon` is an extension of Adobe Utopia which has small caps in all shapes and weights, superior/inferior figures and cyrillic.

Comment: That's pretty much it, but I didn't read Werner's comment thoroughly enough, so I missed it. @egreg's solution below is easier to just cut and paste, so that's hopefully more useful to others later, too.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I was not aware of that font -- looks really good.

Comment: @tanh Unlike a forum, we (and StackExchange's entire model) like to keep answers separate from questions :) I've rolled back your question to its original content.

Comment: @SeanAllred: The unrolling force is strong in you ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The font definition file for Latin Modern doesn't define a `scit` shape, but you can add it, telling LaTeX to substitute `scsl` for it.

You may want to use `fontaxes` instead of `slantsc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{m}{scit}{<->ssub*lmr/m/scsl}{}%
}


\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|)   \par
{\slshape gnu}'s not Unix        (\verb|{\slshape }|) \par
\textit{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|)   \par
\emph{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix}   (\verb|\emph{}|)

\verb|\textsc{}| inside \verb|amsthm| theorem:
\begin{theorem}
  \textsc{gnu}'s not Unix.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to have Palatino, load `mathpazo` for math and `tgpagella` for text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{fontaxes}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|)   \par
\textit{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|)   \par
\emph{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix}   (\verb|\emph{}|)

\verb|\textsc{}| inside \verb|amsthm| theorem:

\begin{theorem}
\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix and math is right
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^{2})\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You get very much alike output with

```
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
```

Take your pick.

Comment: That works perfectly -- I'm in awe. Also, thanks for the tip on `fontaxes`!

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work for Palatino? Neither `scsl` nor `scit` are defined for `pplx`.

Comment: @tanh You may want to try loading tgpagella after mathpazo