# Use specific font for small caps inside emph context

Tags: fonts, small-caps, emphasis, computer-modern

I use `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` to change the font. But CMU Serif doesn’t support small caps emphasis font as you can see with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,twoside,french]{book}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|)   \par
\textit{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|)   \par
\emph{GNU: \textsc{gnu}'s not Unix}   (\verb|\emph{}|)

\end{document}
```

Witch produce the following rendering:

[image: Rendering of the MWE]

But the default font (witch [seems](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/europeancomputermodern/) to be European Computer Modern) produce a well render according to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284338/italic-small-caps-not-working) tread.

So is theire a way to set European Computer Modern just for small caps inside emphasis context (or reverse)?

Comment: the default font in lualatex is Latin Modern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slant the upright small caps

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,twoside,french]{book}
%%%\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[ItalicFeatures= {
SmallCapsFont={CMU Serif},
SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,FakeSlant=0.2} }]



\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|)   \par
\textit{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|)   \par
\emph{GNU: \textsc{gnu}'s not Unix}   (\verb|\emph{}|)

\end{document}
```

Or use Latin Modern small caps
[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,twoside,french]{book}
%%%\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[ItalicFeatures= {
SmallCapsFont=LMRomanCaps10-Oblique}]



\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|)   \par
\textit{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|)   \par
\emph{GNU: \textsc{gnu}'s not Unix}   (\verb|\emph{}|)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm… The slanting still ugly. It’s not a real emphasis. But we could use European Compuuter Modern for all small caps.

Comment: ec fonts are not Unicode encoded opentype so would take some more setup and some lack of warning about incorrect character if you used non ascii letters

Comment: I found a solution working with Latin Modern as described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79086/how-to-use-all-variants-of-latin-modern-roman-with-fontspec/79093#79093 with `LMRomanCaps10-Oblique` instead of ec.

Comment: @fauve ah I tried LM but fontspec didn't find the right font automatically: specifying that variant  explicitly works as you say, I added it above

Answer (score 1):

If you just need slanted/italic small caps for Latin letters, you can substitute with Latin Modern:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[
  SlantedFont=CMU Serif Roman Slanted,
  UprightFeatures={SmallCapsFont=LMRomanCaps10-Regular},
  ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=LMRomanCaps10-Oblique},
  SlantedFeatures={SmallCapsFont=LMRomanCaps10-Oblique},
]

\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|)

\textit{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|)

\emph{GNU: \textsc{gnu}'s not Unix}   (\verb|\emph{}|)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe we can fake `\textsc`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|) \par
\textit{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|) \par
\emph{\textsc{gnu}'s not Unix} (\verb|\emph{}|)

\textsl{\textup{G{\scriptsize NU}}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|) \par
\textit{\textup{G{\scriptsize NU}}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|) \par
\emph{\textup{G{\scriptsize NU}}'s not Unix} (\verb|\emph{}|)

\textsl{G{\scriptsize NU}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textsl{}|) \par
\textit{G{\scriptsize NU}'s not Unix} (\verb|\textit{}|) \par
\emph{G{\scriptsize NU}'s not Unix} (\verb|\emph{}|)

\end{document}
```

[image]