# Italicized small caps words in fancy header?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, small-caps

The following piece of code set the header (chapter names) of my text (*report* class) in small caps:

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\footnotesize}
```

Only problem is that words that are italicized in chapter names are not showed as italicized small caps in the respective headers but instead as "regular" italicized text!

Is there any easy way to fix this? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: The different answers at this question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32942/italic-shape-needed-in-small-caps-fonts, may be of some use.

Comment: Great!  I am, therefore, voting to close the question as a duplicate of the referenced one.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Steven B. Segletes in the comment, it is sufficient to replace `\textit` with `\textsl`.

Comment: Note that this is highly font and configuration dependent.