# Provide smallcaps bold macro

Tags: small-caps

please smallcaps bold tex coding provided?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Not all fonts have bold small caps. Which one do you use?

Comment: if your font has a bold smallcaps then `\textbf{\textsc{Bold Small Caps}}` will work, but if there is no such font, latex can not create it from nothing so you will get a warning that a font is being substituted.

Comment: If you fake the small caps, you can combine it with bold.  SHown here with italic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32942/italic-shape-needed-in-small-caps-fonts/284388#284388.  The key to a reasonable fake is different vertical and horizontal scales.

Answer (score 1):

With the `fontenc` you can get bold small caps, though not for all fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{\textsc{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{document}
```

[image]